# Run Qt application on computer without installed Qt. QCamera don't see available devices

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developping a Network/Gui application. I'm testing the application on another computer, which does not have Qt installed. But when I start the application, [QCamera::availableDevices()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qcamera.html#availableDevices) returns an empty list. When I start this application on the computer which has Qt installed, it returns a list with all cameras on this computer.

I think that the problem is in the `QMultimedia` back-end plugin, which is not loaded automatically. How can I get a list of loaded Qt plugins?

Comment: First try adding all of Qt's DLLs on the other computer, see if it works then. If it works, you know the problem is in some missing DLL.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use qt.conf file approach to set the depending plugins location. As Qt docs say:

> Without qt.conf, the Qt libraries will use the hard-coded paths to
>   look for plugins, translations, and so on. These paths may not exist
>   on the target system, or they may not be accessible. Because of this,
>   you need qt.conf to make the Qt libraries look elsewhere.

[How to use qt.conf](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-conf.html)