# How to set dll search path?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

My goal is keeping all dll's in system folder. But the exe doesn't see some dll's there. Some of them should lay in folder "sqldrivers" and libpq.dll even must lay right near the exe.

Comment: Just add the all the necessary directories to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Please take a look at related quiestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890849/run-qt-application-on-computer-without-installed-qt-qcamera-dont-see-available/18891031#18891031

Answer (score 3):

You should not install Qt DLLs into `C:\Windows` or any subfolder of that directory. You should install the DLLs alongside your executable instead. The alternative is static linking.

Comment: And put the sqldrivers folder inside the same folder that the executable is inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ::SetDllDirectoryA(pathToDlls) in windows.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203(v=vs.85).aspx